# Getting the selected range of the navigator

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighStock chart that renders data for the previous 24hrs, from that data I first want to show only the last 2hrs and allow the users to drag it back if they want to see more.

Is it possible to get the min and max values of the section a user selected?
I tried getExtremes, but this gives me the complete 24hrs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know what are the minimum and maximum datetimes of the currently visible points (that is, the range the user specified in the navigator or in the range selector). If that is the case, just get the `min` and `max` values of the `xAxis` in question.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it. I couldn't imagine that it is so easy.

Comment: If it solves your question then please mark it as answered so that other users know this solves the issue. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

The result of the getExtremes() function looks something like this:

```
Object {
    dataMax: 1374169422743,
    dataMin: 1374169326060,
    max: 1374169381963.2844,
    min: 1374169379331.4294,
    userMax: 1374169381963.2844,
    userMin: 1374169379331.4294
}
```

From what I can tell, the min/max set will match the userMin/userMax set and will also match what you get directly from the xAxis in question. I'm not sure which is the better source

Answer (score 0):

You neet to use setExtremes() http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes() function which allows to degine this range.